# How to extract the mean of pixels in a raster overlapped with a pixel from another raster with a slight geolocation mismatch?

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, raster, python-xarray

I have two rasters (xarray dataarray) with a slight geolocation mismatch in a way that pixels of raster1 overlap with multiple pixels of raster2. I am trying to make some calculations on overlapped pixels in raster2. The below code produce an example:

```
import xarray as xr

LC_val = [[4, 4, 3, 4],
   [3, 3, 3, 6],
   [3, 3, 3, 9]]

VI_val = [[  10,    20,  30,  40],
   [  50,    60,  70,  80],
   [ 90,    100,  110, 120]]

   x_lc = [-1974345., -1974315., -1974285., -1974255.]
   y_lc = [3754475., 3754445., 3754415.]

   x_vi = [-1974371.7598, -1974341.7598, -1974311.7598, -1974281.7598]
   y_vi = [3754465.3842, 3754435.3842, 3754405.3842]

   raster1 = xr.DataArray(LC_val,dims=('y','x'),coords={'x': x_lc,'y': y_lc})
   raster2 = xr.DataArray(VI_val,dims=('y','x'),coords={'x': x_vi,'y': y_vi})
```

Which if we plot them together it looks like:

[image: raster1 and raster2 overlaped]

As an example lets focus on pixel **A** in the figure. It is overlapped with four pixels of raster2 (three of them are visible and one is not). I want to take the weighted mean of these four pixels and assign it to new raster with coordinates similar to pixel A in raster1. The weights are based on the fraction of each pixel (pixels 1-4 in raster2) overlapped with pixel A in raster1.

Based on my search so far there are a couple of ways to do it:

1. create a for loop over each pixel. This is not a good way since I have millions of pixels.
2. convert raster1 into meshgrid polygon and perform zonal statistics with packages such as rasterio. I am not sure this is an efficient way because then we are dealing with millions of polygons.

Is there a better way to do this? Please note that each raster is millions of pixels and the extents and dimensions are different. However, the pixel sizes (30 m) and projection systems are similar.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the option to realign rasters first and then build a simpler logic?

Comment: Not really because the type of analysis requires this kind of calculation.

Comment: Just add to my previous comment that xarray.allign does such alignment.